# How to write generic templated functions taking Eigen Tensor as parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

Best practices for writing functions taking Eigen matrices/arrays are very well documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html). But I am  interested in how to do the same for [Eigen::Tensor](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html) objects and expressions.

More specifically I want to write generic templated functions which takes tensor objects or expression as parameters while doing some operation on them (including resize/modification).

I tried using TensorBase<> as the function parameter, e.g:

```
template<class Derived, int AccessLevel>
void myRankAgnosticFunc(Eigen::TensorBase<Derived, AccessLevel >& tensor) {
  ...
  tensor.derived().resize(...); // Doesn't work since derived() is private
  ....
}
```

However unlike, Eigen::MatrixBase derived() is protected, and cannot be used.

Any suggestions as to how to write generic templated functions with Eigen::Tensor objects?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why `derived()` is protected in `TensorBase`. As a workaround you can cast to `Derived&` yourself like so:

```
Derived& tensr = static_cast<Derived&>(tensor);
// ...
tensr.resize(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply pass the tensor type as a template argument ?

```
template<class MyTensor>
void myRankAgnosticFunc(MyTensor& tensor) {
  ...
  tensor.resize(...);
  ...
```

}

Comment: I agree, in most cases this is sufficient. You lose a bit of type safety, of course. (And I still don't understand, why `derived()` is protected)